# How to get a simple array of DB names with Laravel DB facade?

Tags: laravel

When I do this:

```
$databases = DB::select("SELECT `schema_name` FROM information_schema.schemata");

dd($databases);
```

I get this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#1304
    +"schema_name": "database_name"
  }
]
```

and I want this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "database_name"
]
```

How can I get a simple array with only DB names, or the more important question WHY is that not giving a simple array?

Comment: use `DB::raw()` instead of `DB::select()`

Comment: not working... on my dd(); I get this Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression^ {#1303
  #value: "SELECT `schema_name` FROM information_schema.schemata"
}

Comment: Chain `->pluck('schema_name')`  to the raw expression

Comment: chaining pluck() doesn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
return DB::table('information_schema.schemata')->pluck('schema_name');
```

Comment: That's quick and dirty... not an optimal solution... but it works. More important is why does that query return keys??? Can you explain that?

Comment: Because it executes `fetchAll` behind the scenes, as far as i see from the documentation it maps keys with the values.

Comment: You are right.... that query can't be made with laravel DB facade... I need this: `PDO::FETCH_NUM`

Comment: here is the documentation; https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php this method is invoked without arguments. if it was invoked like this `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)` then  it would fetch all the values of first column.

Comment: sure, looks better.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) on the result which is an array of objects:

```
$result = \DB::select("SELECT `schema_name` FROM information_schema.schemata");

$result = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item->schema_name;
}, $result);

dd($result);
```

The output of `dd` will be something like this:

```
array:7 [▼
    0 => "information_schema"
    1 => "msg_api"
    2 => "mysql"
    3 => "performance_schema"
    4 => "sys"
    6 => "wpblog"
];
```